# TinyMCE: checkboxes are not checkable with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, tinymce

I have a problem with TinyMCE and Internet Explorer.

I need checkboxes in the html-editor but they are not checkable with Internet Explorer 11.

[Picture of the problem in TinyMCE & IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcMxn.png)

Do you have some ideas how to resolve this issue?

I saw the plugin TinyMCE with checklist but it is not what I want.

Sorry for my English (I'm French ^^)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are seeing is that IE does not allow you to interact with form elements in a `contenteditable="true"` setup which is how the TinyMCE editor region is setup.

You could potentially wrap the checkboxes in `contenteditable="false"` spans and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer ! I tried to do this but it didn't work too :/